# Delete a user in powershell Active Directory not working

Tags: powershell

How can I delete a user in an OU in Active Directory with PowerShell script. I tried writing this code under, but it gives me an error

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name "Name".

My code:

```
Remove-ADUser -Name Test -Surname User -GivenName Test -SamaccountName testuser
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is as it says, there isn't a parameter called Name. For [Remove-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617206.aspx) you need to use Identity:

```
Remove-ADUser -Identity ADUser
```